# Firebase keep receiving multiple respond on every new app launch

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

**Issue:**

I have integrated react native firebase v5 to my project. However on every new app launch (**via tapping on the push notification at notification tray**), then on the next push notification that is coming to my mobile will appear twice.

If I do repeat the steps above (**open app via notification from tray**) multiple times, then my application will receive the message from App Server multiple times.

I'm suspecting because every new launch there is a listener being added again into my app?
Also to point out, on every app launch (**open app via notification tray**), componentDidMount is being trigger again.

Any thoughts?

**Code:**

I'm calling the code below my **componentDidMount()**

```
this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase
      .notifications()
      .onNotificationOpened(notificationOpen => {
        const {title, body} = notificationOpen.notification;
        console.log('onNotificationOpened(): open notificaiton, show alert');
        // this.showAlert(title, body);
      });


const notificationOpen = await firebase
      .notifications()
      .getInitialNotification();
    console.log('getInitialNotification()');
    console.log(notificationOpen);
    if (notificationOpen) {
      const {title, body} = notificationOpen.notification;

      // Prevent the alert box keep showing when App Reload
      if (title) {
        console.log(
          'getInitialNotification(): check to see if the application was opened by a notification',
        );
        // this.showAlert(title, body);
      }
    }


this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase
      .notifications()
      .onNotificationOpened(notificationOpen => {
        const {title, body} = notificationOpen.notification;
        console.log('onNotificationOpened(): open notificaiton, show alert');
        // this.showAlert(title, body);
      });
```

**Environment info:**

```
"react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0"

react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5
```